# Rails Client Side Validation install generator not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I am trying to install the Client Side Validation gem in a Rails 5.1.4 app using the instructions at https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations.

I have included `gem 'client_side_validations'` in my Gemfile and ran `bundle install` which ran successfully.

When I try to run the command
`rails g client_side_validations:install`
I get the following error:

`Running via Spring preloader in process 44619
Could not find generator 'client_side_validations:install'.`

And similarly when I try to copy the assets using `rails g client_side_validations:copy_assets`

`Running via Spring preloader in process 44651
Could not find generator 'client_side_validations:copy_assets'.`

What should I do to get this properly installed?

Comment: What happens if you do `spring stop` and then try again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing:

```
spring stop
```

and then trying again.

Roughly, here's what's going on (I may get some specifics not quite correct and others will weigh in).

`spring` pre-loads your environment to speed things up. (Thus the message: `Running via Spring preloader in process 44619`.) However, the environment can go 'stale' if you do things like intall a new gem.

Doing `spring stop`, well, stops `spring` and forces your environment to be re-loaded.

Personally, one of the very first things I do in all of my projects is remove `spring` because the speed increase wasn't worth having to remember to do `spring stop` (especially because I do a lot of custom gem development in parallel with my application development). It is, I suppose, a matter of personal preference.